# I need to run a BAT file on a local PC with IIS and PHP, but not run on server else on client PC

Tags: php, batch-file, iis, local

excuse my English, because I speak Spanish.

good afternoon, I have the following problem:
I have a php page in iis and I need to run a bat file on the local machine (c: \ archibo.bat) but when I try to run it on the server does not on the local computer.
I searched how to do it but I have not found solution.
Thanks to anyone who can help me.

this is my php code:

```
<?php
    system("c:\\archivo.bat");
?>
```

the code try open windows calc, notepad or paint
example: "start calc.exe", "start notepad.exe"

Comment: If you could open ANY file on the client's pc, wouldn't you consider that a security risk? I mean if I could just run `format c: /y` on anyone's computer it would be a problem right?

Answer (score -1):

It's a little unclear, but it sounds like your server is running locally. So that's fine. You just need to change your call a little:

`system("cmd /c c:\archivo.bat");`

Comment: Unsure what the mysterious downvote is for. This works perfectly and is even one of the top comments on the manpage.

Comment: tks, system execute any command dos, but not excecute the command "start"... this´s my problem.